# How can a Dirac delta function that does not occur under an integral be used to describe a transition rate?

Tags: perturbation-theory, dirac-delta-distributions, correlation-functions, fermis-golden-rule

In his excellent notes (found [here](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/stat.mech/lectures/lecture_22/node3.html#SECTION00012000000000000000)), Mark Tuckerman shows that the transition rate of absorption between quantum states *i* and *f*, coupled by operator *B*, can be expressed as the fourier transform of the autocorrelation function of *B*.

Starting with the following expression,

[image: absorption rate defined in terms of the Dirac delta function]

he substitutes the Dirac delta function for its equivalent in integral form,
[image: integral version of Dirac delta function]

and then derives the final result as follows (where *B(t)* below is in the interaction picture representation):

[image: derivation of autocorrelation function]

Textbooks and other sources frequently remind us that the Dirac delta function must appear under an integral in order for it to have physical meaning.  I understand that, in this instance, the Dirac delta function expresses energy conservation for the possible transitions.  However, the absence of an integral seems to suggest infinite rates.

Why in this case is it okay to use the Dirac delta function without a subsequent integration?

Comment: Don't you need to integrate $C_>(\omega)$ to actually use it?

Comment: That's exactly what I was anticipating during the derivation, but at no point is $C_>(\omega)$ integrated over.

Comment: The final result is $C_>(\omega)$ expressed as the fourier transform of an autocorrelation function.

Comment: I wrote "to actually use it", not "during the derivation". How is $C_>(\omega)$ used later on?

Comment: $C_>(\omega)$ is essentially a frequency domain spectrum, the final result, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: It's a kind of density in the frequency space, isn't it.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I found the answer I was looking for on page 9 of the notes located belowhttp://web.mst.edu/~parris/QuantumTwo/Class_Notes/TDPT.pdf

Comment: Are you referring to formula (8.69)?